# Pinterst Integration Android

Tags: android, pinterest

Right now i m using [Pinint Android SDK](http://developers.pinterest.com/android/) download it and integrated with my project but having an issue when i try to [register for client](http://developers.pinterest.com/manage/) this particular url has an error and not letting me to create client id.
I added jar file in to project but still not working when i run project  it crash with the following

```
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.putitout.GREEGS/com.putitout.GREEGS.Menu.ProductDetail}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #358: Error inflating class com.pinterest.external.PinItButton
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #358: Error inflating class com.pinterest.external.PinItButton
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:262)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at com.putitout.GREEGS.Menu.ProductDetail.onCreate(ProductDetail.java:82)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    ... 11 more
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pinterest.external.PinItButton
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
06-26 17:31:11.173: E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    ... 23 more
```

Need help on this Thank you

Answer (score 2):

From the Log its clear that the exception is caused while inflating the widget Pinit Button. I just opened the jar file using my archieve manager and found that "PinItButton"
is not located at the path

```
<com.pinterest.external.PinItButton
```

as documented in sdk.

The actual path is

```
<com.pinterest.pinit.PinItButton
```

Substitute the above path for your Pinit button in XML and the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this please remove the **button** code from `Xml`, rather create the **button** using `Java`. Then this problem will be solved.

**For Example**

```
    RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.v);    
    PinItButton pinIt = new PinItButton(this);
    view.addView(pinIt);
```

Comment: this is alternate solution. What about the question? Do you have that?

Comment: @Chintan Rathod Please see through my answer.